# How to get paises from relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I've `FabricanteDistribuidor.php` entity with this code:

```
class FabricanteDistribuidor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Pais", mappedBy="fabricanteDistribuidor", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $paises;


    /**
     * Set paises
     *
     * @param  \AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais
     * @return FabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function setPaises(\Sencamer\AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais)
    {
        $this->paises[] = $pais;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paises
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPaises()
    {
        return $this->paises;
    }

}
```

And the related `Pais.php` entity code:

```
class Pais
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;
    use ActiveEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sencamer\AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor", inversedBy="paises", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.fabricante_distribuidor_pais", schema="negocio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_distribuidor", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pais_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $fabricanteDistribuidor;

    /**
     * Add fabricanteDistribuidor
     *
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor $fabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function addfabricanteDistribuidor(\AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor $fabricanteDistribuidor)
    {
        $this->fabricanteDistribuidor[] = $fabricanteDistribuidor;
    }

    /**
     * Get fabricanteDistribuidor
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getfabricanteDistribuidor()
    {
        return $this->fabricanteDistribuidor;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get now the related `paises` from `FabricanteDistribuidor`as follow and I'm doing something wrong since I can't get their names, so what is wrong in my code?

```
public function obtenerDetallesFabricanteAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:FabricanteDistribuidor')->find($request->query->get('id'));

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response['entities'] = array();

        $dataResponse = array();
        // rest of columns  .... 

        if ($entity->getPaises() instanceof Pais) {
            $paises = array();
            foreach ($entity->getPaises() as $pais) {
                $paises[] = $pais->getNombre();
            }

            $dataResponse['paises'] = $paises;
        }

        $response['entities'][] = $dataResponse;
        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Maybe the right way is go through a DQL in a Doctrine Repository but then is the performance problem and here I'm not an expert so need a clue or a workaround on this.

Now with this same classes I've also a concern related the `Pais` class because as you notice I added the inversed side `$fabricanteDistribuidor` so, do I have to insert this any time I want to insert a new `Pais` or is just to tell Doctrine how to deal with proxies inside it? I've not clear yet how owning/inversed side works yet maybe due to this I did thing as my code shown. Any advice around this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you're missing to initialize `$paises` (and also `$fabricanteDistribuidor`) collection? Shouldn't it be look like this?:

```
class FabricanteDistribuidor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Pais", mappedBy="fabricanteDistribuidor", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $paises;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->paises = new ArrayCollection(); // don't forget to import it
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem I still getting NULL